# How to set scss syntax in Sublime 3?

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext3, sublimetext, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Sublime 3 editor. When I open a SCSS file it shows many red characters because it misjudged the syntax. When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type `sass` or `scss` I get no option. I had to set syntax to CSS.

Is there any way to set syntax to SCSS in Sublime 3?

Comment: ST3 doesn't support SCSS/SASS out the box, try installing the third party package like https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Syntax%20Highlighting%20for%20Sass

Answer (score 169):

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in Submile Text below popup opens

[image]

Click on the **Package Control: Install Package**.which will open the below popup. Type **SCSS** in the search box. Look for exactly: **SCSS** (it may not be the first thing that comes up) and click on it.

[image]

again press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and search for SCSS and click on the **Set Syntax: SCSS**. that it your scss files will be colored accordingly

[image]

Comment: A note: Package Control may noy be installed by default

Comment: @user31782 Do you mind accepting this answer so that others can find the solution more easily?

Comment: I don't know why but after installing the linter, I cant set the syntax. It's not offered as an option.

Comment: @elliottregan I think by the time this answer was posted, I stopped participating on stack exchange network. I don't do programming anymore so it is not possible for me to accept it. Sorry mate.

Answer (score 43):

There are two very popular packages: 'Sass', and 'SCSS'. I started with the 'SCSS' package, given that codegeek's 72+ answer suggests it, but I found that a large amount of my valid SCSS was just white.

The ['Sass'](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sass) package contains both Sass and SCSS, and is much more complete for SCSS than the package just called 'SCSS'.

Steps to install:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Type '`Package Control: Install package`' and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Wait several seconds
3. Type '`Sass`', ensure the selected item is just '`Sass`', and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. You'll see installation status in the status bar at the bottom of the app. When finished installing:
5. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> again
6. Type '`Set syntax: SCSS`' and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Any tips on syntax specific spaces? for me when pressing enter it still makes 4 spaces even though there should be 2 as per syntax specific file for scss

Comment: I confirm that the SASS 2.0 plugin is much better than the SCSS plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Sass extension installed (which supports both SASS and SCSS) and you want all `.scss` files to open with the newer SCSS syntax highlighting rather than the older SASS, then do the following:

- Open ***View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as...***
- Select ***Sass -> SCSS***

Credit: http://joncaveman.com/2015/08/11/sublime-text-3-default-syntax-highlighting-for-file-types/